UDPipe 2 Models in R
I am not entirely happy with udpipe 2.5. Latin models available through the library udpipe, and looking for a way to use newer (2.12 or 2.14) models listed here.
However, it seems that they are only available in Python:

Compared to UDPipe 1, it is Python-only, it does not perform tokenization, and the models require more computation power (here).

I am not a Python user at all, is there a way to use these models in R?
So far, I have been able to download a huge archive with the newer conllu-files (from here) and trying to train a model as described here. However, it does not lead to a significantly better result.

I think you should be able to download the model onto your computer and then load it the regular way in UDPipe

I don't think that models with .udpipe extension (necessary for the udpipe package) are available so far. As far as I can judge, the issue is still open.
